# how do i call a procedure (In and out parameter) using java with property file and make it more generic?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a procedure that has one in parameter and two out parameters.
I would like to make my code more generic in such a way that,
if in future any procedure will come then I will just create one properties file of it and update.
Code will automatically work accordingly and setString and RegisterOut parameters.

Comment: So what is stopping you?   (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *"I wanted to make code more generic"* . This is not how Oracle works. RDBMS products are strongly data-typed and PL/SQL is strongly data-typed. Write a procedure which works for you now. If you get new requirements write a new procedure. If your requirements change write a new procedure (or change the existing procedures). PL/SQL is not Java.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:  Stop reinventing the wheel.
Use an existing tool to solve this problem.

Accept This:
You will never encounter a problem that has never before been encountered.
You will never come up with a totally new and novel technique for solving a problem.
Every problem we will ever encounter was solved in the 1960s;
all we encounter is new variations of problems.
All we will ever do is create variations of solutions that already exist.

Whether or not you believe the statement above,
you are planning to do nothing new.

Everything you will ever want to do with a database has already been solved by Hibernate, MyBatis, and other JDBC tools.
Note that these are more than "just JDBC tools",
but they cover all of the JDBC stuff you will ever need or want to do.

Choose one of those and
read the documentation.

MyBatis is likely to be a good option,
since it is lighter weight than Hibernate.